# What is causing the memory leak in this for loop?

Tags: c

```
for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS; k++) {
    if(slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL) {
        slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
    } else slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
}
```

When I run valgrind, I get an error of invalid size 8.

Note that `MAXRECORDS = 10`, and the array size is `MAXRECORDS`.

I assume this has something to do with a border case in my for loop, but I don't understand logically how it's happening.

EDIT: It was pointed out that on the last round of the for loop, accessing `servers_ptr[k+1]` is outside of the array, causing valgrind errors. I have since updated my code to:

```
for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS-1; k++) {
    if(slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL) {
            slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
            if(k==MAXRECORDS-2)slist->servers_ptr[k+1] = NULL;
    } else slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
}
```

I still get the errors in valgrind. Did I update it incorrectly?

Comment: Then my answer below is correct.

Comment: You're not doing any `malloc` or `realloc` here. Do you really think that there is some memory leak problem with this code? I think the problem might be with some other code snippet where you are allocating memory.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong. Can you post the exact errors you get from valgrind?

Comment: If all you're doing is shifting the partial contents of an array, why not use `memmove()` to do the shift and assign `NULL` to the last element?  It beats reinventing one of the tools C gives you, makes your code easier to read and will run faster on some platforms because the compiler can optimize the operation on CPUs that have block memory move instructions.

Comment: @c0da The memory leak could be because by shifting the elements in the array, one loses the reference to the first one. If there isn't any other reference to it in the code, it cannot be cleaned up and will be leaked.

Comment: Great! Now if he posts the input values (because there are `NULL`s involved here), we might be able to help him.

Answer (score 3):

`servers_ptr` is of size `MAXRECORDS`. In this last iteration of your for loop, `k == MAX_RECORDS - 1`. You access `servers_ptr[k+1]` which will be `servers_ptr[MAX_RECORDS]` which is one past the end of the array. This is undefined behavior and valgrind flags it.

```
            for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS; k++) {
                    if(slist->servers_ptr[k+1] != NULL) {
                            slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
                    } else slist->servers_ptr[k] = NULL;
            }
```

Consider that else clause. Its the same as:

```
slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
```

Because we know that `slist->server_ptr[k+1]` is NULL because we failed the if condition. But this means both branches of the if are the same. So the code is equivalent to:

```
            for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS; k++) {
                slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
            }
```

So what you are doing is shifting all the pointers to the left like this:

```
[1][2][3][4][5]
[2][3][4][5][?]
```

You code tries to shift one value to many and ends up pulling garbage from somewhere.

The solution is to copy one less item and handle the last cell as a special case.

```
            for(k=i; k<MAXRECORDS-1; k++) {
                slist->servers_ptr[k] = slist->servers_ptr[k+1];
            }
            slist->servers_ptr[MAXRECORDS-1] = NULL;
```